# Setting maximum height for a ScrollView dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-scrollview, android-dialog

I have a dialog that's a `NestedScrollView`. Inside there are some widgets.

Right now, if the phone has a small enough density, the alert is scrollable - which is CORRECT.

What I'd like to change is how "how small enough" the density has to be before it becomes scrollable. My solution to that is to use some space not used by the dialog, see the pic below:

[image]

Basically I want to decrease the space indicated by the arrows IF NEEDED.

So how do I increase the maximum height of the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

I advise using ConstraintLayout and put that scrollView inside it. Then you can give that scrollView percentHeight(percentWidh). It just works as you want. It takes the device screen which is runs and uses the percent of that screen. For example, if you give 0.5 as a percent it will take half of the screen that the application run

Comment: I don't understand. `NestedScrollView` doesn't have a `percentHeight` attribute.

Comment: @LeNguyenDuyAnh if you put that nestedScrollView inside ConstraintLayout, then it will have